# Is locking the most accurate pattern to manage a schedule?

Tags: python, multithreading, locking, python-multithreading

Problem that I have to solve with Python is managing a schedule. I will have 2 main processes:

- Process A: Execution each X minutes. It will query for pending activity and it will assign 3 possible free time slots for each pending task (blocking these calendar's slots).
- Process B: Always executing. This process should wait for arriving of one acceptation of 3 possible slots for each task. When acceptation arrives, process should confirm selected calendar's slot and free non selected slots in order to put available for the other process

My idea is using locking in order to ensure the acquisition of the schedule only for one process at a time.
Any suggestion about this?

Comment: What do you mean, "accurate"? It works, in the sense that it avoids race conditions. And with two processes it's unlikely that you will have a contention issue with a **single** lock.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. About "accurate" I just wanted to know if it's a good idea using locking :) I have read that using "with" statement with Condition object is a good aproximation

Comment: Assuming that you mean _mutual exclusion_ when you say "locking." A good time to use it is when one entity (thread or process) needs to make changes to data that are shared with other entities, and it is important to prevent those other entities from seeing the data in a half-way-changed state. What you should _not_ try to do with mutual exclusion alone is, to coordinate activities of different entities. E.g., if you want one process to _wait_ for another process to do some thing, then there are other, better tools (e.g., semaphores, message queues) for that.